# How to convert a variable with yes or no values to 1 and 0 in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, type-conversion

I'm working on an employee attrition dataset. There is a column named attrition and it contains 1470 yes and no values. I want to convert these yes and no values to 1 and 0. I installed the dplyr package in R to use the mutate function but I'm having trouble converting. Here's what I tried:

`clean %>% mutate(empAttrcopy$attrition=ifelse(empAttrcopy$attrition=="NO",0,1)) Error: unexpected '=' in "clean %>% mutate(empAttrcopy$attrition="`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `attrition` contains only "YES" or "NO" values, this should work. First some reproducible data:

```
set.seed(42)
attrition <- sample(c("YES", "NO"), 15, replace=TRUE)
attrition
#  [1] "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES" "NO"  "NO"  "NO"  "NO"  "YES" "NO"  "YES" "NO"  "YES" "NO"  "YES"
attrition <- as.numeric(attrition=="YES")
attrition
#  [1] 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

I've left off the `empAttrcopy$` prefix for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have a dataframe called "empAttrcopy", want to dummy code the column "attrition" and store it to a new dataframe called "clean".

When using `dplyr`, the pipe `%>%` (originally from `magrittr`) evaluates what's on the left side of it and feeds the result as input to the next function on the right. So if you want to mutate a column within "empAttrcopy", you need to put it before the first `%>%`. When having done that, R knows that you are working with "Attrition", so there's no need to backreference it after piping (i.e. no need for `$`).

```
empAttrcopy %>% mutate(attrition = ifelse(attrition == "No", 0, 1))
```

If you want to store the output of your mutated column to a new dataframe called "clean", do so by assigning it by using `<-` at the start or `->` at the end.

```
clean <- empAttrcopy %>% mutate(attrition = ifelse(attrition == "No", 0, 1))

# or

empAttrcopy %>% mutate(attrition = ifelse(attrition == "No", 0, 1)) -> clean
```

Last but not least, it's always better to store the output in a new column (e.g. save it to "attrition_dummy"), so that you don't lose any data.

```
clean <- empAttrcopy %>% mutate(attrition_dummy = ifelse(attrition == "No", 0, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `ifelse` function available on the `base` package. This allows an expression to be evaluated and assigned values ​​as appropriate.

```
a = c(5,7,2,9)
(a %% 2 == 0,"even","odd")

[1] "odd"  "odd"  "even" "odd"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
empAttrcopy$attrition=ifelse(empAttrcopy$attrition=="YES", 1 , 0)

empAttrcopy$attrition1=ifelse(empAttrcopy$attrition=="YES", 1 , 0)
```

I usually add new columns, to have the original variable `attrition` and newly created `attrition1` for comparison. YES=1, NO=0.

Cheers!